# MySQL SELECT based on aggregate of multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in MySQL with a number of normal fields and a number of "approval" fields that contain a `1` if the data in question is approved and a `0` otherwise. For example,

```
*==============================================================*
* id  |  fname  | lname | fname_approved | lname_approved | ...*
*--------------------------------------------------------------*
* ... |   ...   |  ...  |        0       |        1       | ...*
```

In reality, there are many more columns, but it is just more of the same. What I would like to be able to do is select a single value, say `all_approved` that would be equal to 1 if *all* of the `_approved` fields contain 1 and would be equal to 0 if *any* of the fields contain a 0. Is there any easy way to do this in SQL, or do I need to handle it in my application logic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use multiplication like

```
select (fname_approved * lname_approved) as all_approved from my_table;
```

this way if any of the _approved is 0 then all_approved will be 0 otherwise 1

Comment: That works great for this table! What if, hypothetically, the database design was horrible and another table kept track of approvals with a CHAR(1) column that could be set to 'y' or 'n'. Do you know of a technique that would work there?

Comment: @Andrew for this char column you can use `CASE WHEN 'y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`

Comment: I can come up with workarounds ( like concatenate all columns and then search for 'n' in the result string) but nothing straight forward as a built in function.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query as,

```
SELECT IF(fname_approval = 1 && lname_approval   = 1 && mname_approval= 1, 'all_approved ', 'Not-Approved') AS approved_status 
from table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

If the number of approval columns is fixed and the values in them is either 0 or 1, then some thing like this would help

```
Select (fname_approval + lname_approval + mname_approval) from <table_name>
```

This query would give you the total, say 3.. which would mean all have been approved as the number of columns is same as the total. If the total is less, it would mean you don't have all the approvals.

You need to hard code the number of columns(which isn't a good idea). Hope this helps.

Comment: Desislav Kamenov, has better approach by multiplying the values. +1 for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  case 
    when  fname_approved=1 and lname_approved=1  then 1 as all_approved
    else 0 as not_approved
  end ;
 from my_table
```